# Finding pairs of mobile nodes in a 2D space within a given Euclidean distance?

Tags: algorithm, graph, simulation, graph-algorithm

I'm looking to simulate mobile devices that are placed in a 2D space and have a fixed, limited communication range. I need to be able to determine which pairs of nodes are within range of each other and make sure that edges are updated accordingly when the vertices move into or out of range. I expect to have on the order of 1000 nodes or more, so doing a full pairwise comparison ( O(n^2) ) each time step is infeasible. Vertices will move using different direction and velocity, so I assume 'predictive' methods that anticipate a path would be just as difficult. I assume that all vertices have the same communication radius.

An existing simulation environment or Java library is ideal, but an algorithm will also be helpful. Hardware simulation environments like ns-2 are extreme overkill for the simple functionality I'm looking for.

Comment: can you please give details about the parameters that you need to pair the decvices and constraints on pairing and clusters....

Comment: The only parameter is r, the distance between vertices in the 2D plane that are allowed to communicate. Otherwise, there are no other constraints on which pairs can form.

Answer (score 2):

A typical easy solution is to divide the space into a grid. If the communication range is R, you could use e.g. R as the grid spacing factor. In each cell of the grid, you continuously maintain a list / set of those nodes that belong to that cell. Now, in order to find the neighbors of a mobile device M it is enough to check for the mobile devices within its own cell, and the neighbors of that cell. Obviously, you can use other spacing factors also. This speeds up a lot if not every mobile device is connected to every other.

Answer (score 0):

As said by @antti.huima , we should divide the eucliden space into grids but finding the size of the grid will be requirement  dependent . Im not sure whether we can make the cluster out of grid but making cluster would be more efficient .
Suppose the mobile move a bit by delta.. and moves out of cluster say C1 to the neighbouring cluster say c2 so our mobile should be paired with all the mobiles of given range in the cluster say C2... so in this process we dont need to update the pairing event with all the rest of N-1 elements but only with the elements that are there in the cluster . we furthur suppose that the  cluster radius be 2R where R is range of mobile in my asumption. So when a cluster moves from  C1 to neighbouring Cluster then there will be atmost 8 to 10 cluster(imagine as circles) around it so the node or mobile should be compared with elements of this 8 to 10 cluster of elements .. in this way we are minimizing the number pairings